# What is actually happening when a magnetoresistive magnetometer degausses itself?

Tags: magnetic-fields, measurements

I'm trying to understand if anisotropic magnetoresistive devices themselves (not other passive ferromagnetic components) can become magnetized, and if so, how the application of a DC 1.1 gauss field can "degauss" them.

I started with [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/249086/102305) in electronics stackexchange, *but here I'd like to understand better what is happening inside a magnetoresistive device itself.*

If they themselves can become magnetized, how could a simple on-off step of 1.1 gauss "degauss" them. I'm familiar with degaussing where a much stronger, AC field is applied, and slowly and steadily ramped down in amplitude, but this is very different.

The discussion in the other question is related to the internal degaussing feature of [this anisotropic magnetoresistive magnetometer](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf):

> Set/Reset and Offset Strap Drivers for Degaussing, Self Test, and
>   Offset Compensation

and there is a short mention of the need for internal degaussing at the bottom of the second page in [this FAQ](http://www.digikey.tw/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/HoneywellSSEC_342/pdf/honeywell-mps-faqs.pdf):

> Rotation of the sensor should vary the output voltage. If it does not, the part maybe "permed" due to strong magnetic fields over 20 gauss such as accidental proximity of magnetized tips of some hand tools during assembly. Performing the application of current pulses across the set/reset strap should degauss the sensor(s) and restore performance.

Everything is relative - in this context, 20 gauss is "strong"!

There may be some helpful background information in [this presentation](http://magnetism.eu/esm/2015/slides/tiusan-slides1.pdf) at `magnetism.eu`.

[image]

**above:** screenshot from the [Honeywell HMC5883L datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf), a "3-Axis Magnetoresistive Sensors and ASIC in a 3.0 x 3.0 x 0.9mm LCC Surface
Mount Package."

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but the applied field does not degauss the sensor but actually it _magnetizes_ the sensor, so that the magnetization is directed along the sensor axis.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you for your comment! That makes quite a lot of sense; in this case "degauss" might only mean to change the magnetization from an unknown state (direction and magnitude) to a state that is known. If this turns out to be the case, then a description of "*what is happening inside a magnetoresistive device itself.*" during this *magnetization* process would be the answer.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano any further thoughts? I'd hate to let this bounty go to waste :-)

Comment: Sorry for the bounty: I could write an answer if only I had the time, but these days I'm really overwhelmed by work and I can barely breathe :-(

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano oh no problem. Sorry to hear about the situation, *please* take a moment now and then to breathe whenever possible ;-) Good luck!